# Enable font slashed zero

Tags: html, css

I tried font-variant-numeric: slashed-zero but it does not show the slashed zero for my font.  How do you use stylistics alternates with css to show slashed zero?

Comment: Please add the code you tried - [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried `font-variant-numeric: slashed-zero;` ? It is also only available for OpenType fonts https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric

Comment: yes I tried font-variant-numeric: slashed-zero.